# NullPointerException during executing program with GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create my first program in Java that uses GUI and I have small problem. I created a window using NetBeans and now I'm createing two more classes - one called GUI that will be controlling my window and of course Main.

Here are codes of both:

GUI:

```
package client;

import resources.gui.*;

public class GUI {
    public Window window; 
    public GUI(){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                window=new Window();
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public void Show(){
        window.jTextArea1.setText("Test");
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package client;

public class Main {

    static GUI gui;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui=new GUI();
        gui.Show();
    }
}
```

And of course there is one more called Window that extends JFrame.

My problem is that while executing it, there is java.lang.NullPointerException in line that tries to modify jTextArea1. I guess that is because when program is trying to use this function there is no Window class - it hasn't been created yet "thanks to" invokeLater.

If I'm right how can I repair it? There is no way to put that function into run() because in final version it won't be a function - it will be Thread class independent from GUI, that will be created and executed in Main... or at least I would like it to be like that. :)

Comment: Where do you create JTextArea1? If you don't create it, how do you expect it to exist? It is null, hence you get the NullPointerException (as the program is trying to call the method setText on a null object).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the Window class.

You do not instantiate jTextArea1. It is of a null value (a null pointer; since variable names for objects are, in effect, pointers).

If you were to modify the code, expand it out like so, this would show you where the error is:

```
JTextArea myTextArea = window.jTextArea1;
myTextArea.setText("Test");
```

Of course, since this is still broken, this isn't exactly what you want. You want to create the JTextArea (and there's [ample examples online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jtextarea%20example)).